# C# word boundary regex instead of .Contains() needed

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, linq, word-boundary

I have a list:

```
var myList = new List<string> { "red", "blue", "green" };
```

I have a string:

```
var myString = "Alfred has a red and blue tie";
```

I am trying to get a count of matches of words in `myList` within `myString`.  Currently, I am using `.Contains()`, which gets me a count of 3 because it is picking up the "red" in "Alfred".  I need to be able to osolate words instead.  How can this be achieved?

```
var count = myList.Where(ml => myString.Contains(ml)); // gets 3, want 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        var myList = new List<string> { "red", "blue", "green" };
        Regex r = new Regex("\\b(" + string.Join("|", myList.ToArray()) + ")\\b");
        MatchCollection m = r.Matches("Alfred has a red and blue tie");
```

m.Count will give you the number of times red, blue or green are found.  \b specifies word boundary.

Each element of m is of Type Match, and you can look at each index to get more info (ie m[0].Value gives you the matched string (red) and m[0].Index gives you the location in the original string (13)).

Comment: Excellent answer, that would have been my answer as well +1

Comment: +1 - If I had any RegExFu whatsoever, I'd go with this answer because it will properly handle punctuation, etc.

Comment: Is there a way to get the results of what is found.  In this case a list containing "red","blue"?  How about their index/positions relative to the original string?  (Is this another question?)

Comment: @Brian - sure can, I updated the answer (m[x].Value and m[x].Index).

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = (from s in myList
            join ms in myString.Split() on s equals ms
            select new { s, ms }).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var numMatches = myString.Split().Intersect(myList).Count();
```

Note that this doesn't consider duplicate occurrences.

If you do want to consider duplicates, go with @Justin Niessner's technique.
Here's an alternative, with an intermediary lookup:

```
var words = myString.Split().ToLookup(word => word);
var numMatches = myList.Sum(interestingWord => words[interestingWord].Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

this works
\bred\b|\bblue\b|\bgreen\b
I am not sure it is most optimized